# Problem with the functions torch.rfft() and torch.irfft()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I need to run the code that was written for the old version of PyTorch. I have version 1.9. Starting from version 1.8, PyTorch introduced the functions `torch.fft.rfft()` and `torch.fft.irfft()`, which work differently from the old `torch.rfft()` and `torch.irfft()`. I couldn't figure out how to replace these functions so that this code works exactly the same as on the old version:

version 1.8:

```py
    fU = torch.rfft( u, 1, onesided=False)
    U = torch.irfft(fU, 1, onesided=False)
    torch.fft(x, x.ndim)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, `torch.rfft()` and `torch.irfft()` have differences with `torch.fft.rfft()` and `torch.fft.irfft()` in formats of inputs and outputs. (See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/The-torch.fft-module-in-PyTorch-1.7)

Following [the issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/49637) in GitHub page of PyTorch, I made changes for two-dimensional operation as below:

```py
spectrum = torch.fft.rfft2(signal)
spectrum = torch.complex(spectrum[..., 0], spectrum[..., 1])
signal_recovered = torch.fft.irfft2(spectrum)
```